# Cannot read property 'length' of undefined C# JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, html, entity-framework

I have a problem when displaying my database data, the following code I use to send my data to call

```js
var table;
$(document).ready(function() {
  const cargandoGeneral = Swal.mixin({
    title: 'Cargando datos ...',
    allowOutsideClick: false,
    showCancelButton: false,
    showConfirmButton: false
  });

  table = $('#tabla').DataTable({
    language: {
      url: "/Assets/js/Spanish.json",
    },
    processing: true,
    serverSide: true,
    ajax: {
      type: "POST",
      url: "/tableroOTFamilia/Listar",
      beforeSend: function(data) {
        cargandoGeneral({
          title: 'Cargando datos ...',
          allowOutsideClick: false,
          showCancelButton: false,
          showConfirmButton: false
        });
      },
      complete: function(data) {
        cargandoGeneral.close();
      },
      error: function(request, status, error) {
        swal({
          type: 'error',
          title: 'Oops...',
          text: request.responseText
        });
      }
    },
    columnDefs: [{
      width: "8%",
      targets: 0,
      searchable: false
    }],
    columns: [{
        data: "Id",
        "render": function(Id) {
          return '<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" onclick="eliminar(' + Id +
            ');"><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></button> <button type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-sm" onclick="cargar(' + Id +
            ');"><i class="fas fa-pencil-alt"></i></button>';
        }
      },

      //{ data: "Id" },
      {
        data: "descripcion"
      },
    ]
  });

});
```

At the time of inspecting in the browser I throw this error

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nigbR.png)

This is my code from my table in the view

```html
<table id="tabla" class="table table-striped table-bordered dataTable" style="width:100%;">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Editar</th>
      @*
      <th>Id</th>*@
      <th>Descripción</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
</table>



<div id="modal_form" class="modal fade bd-example-modal-lg" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myLargeModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" style="max-width: 60% !important; margin:auto !important;">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Familia</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
     <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
    </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form id="formulario">
          <input type="hidden" id="id" name="id" />
          <div class="form-group row">
            <label for="nombreCompleto" class="col-sm-2 col-form-label">Descripción</label>
            <div class="col-sm-9">
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="descripcion" name="descripcion" required>
            </div>
          </div>

        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <div id="divBotones">
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="btnGuardar"> <i class="fas fa-upload"></i> Guardar </button>
          <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal"><i class="fas fa-times"></i> Cerrar</button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the following code is that of my controller (tableroOTFamilia) and my method Listar, which is what I call to call from my javascript

```html
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult Listar(FormCollection forms)
{
      try
            {
                int draw = 1;
                int start = 0;
                int length = 10;
                string search = null;
                int recordsFiltered = 10;

                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(forms["draw"].ToString()))
                {
                    draw = int.Parse(forms["draw"].ToString());
                }
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(forms["start"].ToString()))
                {
                    start = int.Parse(forms["start"].ToString());
                }
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(forms["length"].ToString()))
                {
                    length = int.Parse(forms["length"].ToString());
                }
                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(forms["search[value]"].ToString()))
                {
                    search = forms["search[value]"].ToString();
                }

                ModeloTableroOT.ModeloTableroOTContainer db = new ModeloTableroOTContainer();
                var result = (from b in db.tableroOTFamiliaSet
                              select b).OrderBy(a => a.descripcion).ToList<tableroOTFamilia>();


                if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(search))
                {
                    result = result.Where(a => a.descripcion.Contains(search)
                    ).ToList<tableroOTFamilia>();

                }

                List<cTableroOTOperacionCDO> lista = new List<cTableroOTOperacionCDO>();

                foreach (var registro in result)
                {
                    cTableroOTOperacionCDO o = new cTableroOTOperacionCDO();
                    o.Id = registro.Id;
                    o.descripcion = registro.descripcion;


                    lista.Add(o);
                }


                if (result == null)
                {
                    return Json(new
                    {
                        status = false,
                        mensaje = "No se encontraron registros de familias en el catálogo",
                        data = lista,
                        draw = draw,
                        JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
                    });
                }

                var res = lista.Skip(start).Take(length);
                recordsFiltered = lista.Count();

                return Json(new
                {
                    status = true,
                    mensaje = "Datos cargados",
                    data = res,
                    draw = draw,
                    recordsTotal = lista.Count(),
                    recordsFiltered = recordsFiltered,
                    JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
                });
            }
}
```

What I understand the error is at the moment of listing my information, I just do not see what the error may be, and verify that my columns must be out of ajax If you need more information I will be aware

Comment: Doesn't look like you're doing anything with the data returned form your server.